# Question closed by community, since edited. Flag for moderator attention?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've had a question closed by the community, i.e. five 3K users, not a diamond mod, and I've tried improving it. What should I do now? Wait? Flag for moderator attention? Cast a re-open vote? Discuss it on the (heavily polluted by off-topic discussion) chat room?

Comment: Voting to reopen is good. Or flagging, depending on what mood the mod who sees the flag is in. Or posting on meta. Or chat. Anything, really.

Comment: Has the question by now been reopened? I can't find a recently closed question of yours.

Comment: @StoneyB simchona said she voted to re-open it; that means she actually re-opened it, as a moderator's vote is [binding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192/140449).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I voted to reopen your question. As waiwai mentioned, there are several options to get a question reopened, all of which are valid. You can flag the question, vote to reopen it, post on Meta, or ask people in chat to take a second look.